# Cooking Android

Tags: android, compilation, operating-system

Can someone consider and evaluate my approach to customization of Froyo? I'm a beginner.

I've download the sources from Android website and i've successfull recompiled and run it on my (study) device.
Let's consider a trivial customization: on Settings activity the last choice is something like 'Info about the phone' but... my device is not a phone so i want to replace this string.

Once moved to *[my froyo]*/packages/apps/Settings/res/values i've edited the 'string.xml' file with the right value. At this point my problems begin...

Considering that i've the Java compiler, how can i recompile only the (i.e.) Settings apk and not the entire operating system *(my solution has been to **recompile** the whole operating system)*???

Once obtained the *NEW* Settings.apk, how can i upload it to my device substituting the previous (system) one? I've tryed 'adb install' with all the options but it fails; i've tryed 'adb unistall' on the previous (system) one but it fails as well. *(my solution was to **upload** again the whole operation system)*.

In conclusion, how can i change a string from 'phone' in 'squirrel' without spending an hour? I want only to customize a little bit the system applications. I'd like to edit the source, try it on device and only once that all the customizations have been done recompile the operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay lets start with the first question. To recompile a specific package you can just type

```
make <PackageName>
```

in your case it should be make Settings.

Then after the new package was compiled you will find it in the build directory.

copy the apk directly to the /system/app folder in your device and delete the /data/dalvik-cache/ entry for it and reboot the device, the new package should be loaded.

For making the /system partition writable you need to type

```
adb remount
```

But note that some Packages may have dependencies which might be needed for your customization. Something like the framework_res.apk